# Firefox's clientHeight and scrollHeight

Tags: firefox, dom, firefox6

I am experiencing problem with detecting an overflow inside a div. I'm using firebug to debug my html.

In my firebug I see that my div has the same clientHeight and scrollHeight, even though Firefox rendered it with a vertical scrollbar (which should mean the scrollHeight > clientHeight right?)

Is this a known bug? I haven't tested it with another browser.
Are there any workaround for this?

FYI my div is overflow:auto and I'm using Firefox 6.0

Comment: Works for me ( http://jsfiddle.net/BX7XW/ ). Please provide a repro URL.

Comment: Hmm yes, I have made myself a test HTML and it worked too.. I have to do more investigation on this

Comment: This turns out to be my fault. I have compared the wrong div. Actually there is a lot of div container in my page. This made me confused. Anyway now already solved.